# Building OpenSSL on Xcode 4.3 for Simulator fails

Tags: ios, openssl, ios-simulator, static-libraries, xcode4.3

> **Alternate titles (to aid search):**
>
> - Xcode Build Phase script fails
> - Xcode fail with "make[1]: cc: No such file or directory"
> - Building for simulator fails, building for device works
> - Xcode fails to build for i386, but will for armv6 & armv7

I have the OpenSSL Xcode project that uses a **Build Phase** script to compile the `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` static libraries for iOS (it also works for Mac OS X).

Building for `device` works with no issues the `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` are created and can be linked into projects.

However, trying to build the same libraries for the `simulator` causes a build error:

```
cc -I. -I.. -I../include  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -UOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk   -c -o cryptlib.o cryptlib.c
make[1]: cc: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [cryptlib.o] Error 1
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

There seems to little difference between the settings, the only variable is the architecture; `armv7` verses `i386`.

Comment: A bit off topic, but since I just submitted this as a bug that affects iOS: [SSL_read / SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ / ENOTCONN infinite loop](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2759)

Comment: What do you mean by "the OpenSSL Xcode project that uses a Build Phase script to compile the libcrypto.a and libssl.a static libraries for iOS (it also works for Mac OS X)."  That's not a standard part of openssl as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 8):

Beginning with Xcode 4.3 Apple stopped bundling command line tools as standard with Xcode.

This issues is caused by Xcode trying to use different compilers for Device (armv6 & armv7) and Simulator (i386).

In a build phase script for armv6 & armv7 Xcode will use the bundled tools (in the question the `cc` (clang) compile). But for simulator builds, build phase scripts use the system versions.

If you haven't explicitly installed the tools the build will fail.

To install the tools select `Xcode > Preferences > Downloads`

[image: Xcode Prefs]

And click on "Install" for "Command Line Tools".